# How to fix truncated text on <select> element on iOS8

Tags: select, ios8, truncated

Is there any way to prevent iOS8 from truncating the text when selecting an option on a html select element? iOS8 truncates the text on the options text instead of wrapping it. The previous suggestions for iOS7 are not working

Answer (score 0):

The empty optgroup was never a good solution. Wrapping all the options in an optgroup works, however it does make the text quite small and if the text is longer than what will fit on two lines, the text will be truncated without any indication that it's been truncated.